# Hibernate Treats SQL Server Dateparts as Columns Instead of Keywords

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

We have an entity column with a formula property that requires today's date at midnight in order to calculate itself property:

```
DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Hibernate transforms this into:

```
DATEADD(mytablename0_.DD, DATEDIFF(mytablename0_.DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

I've double checked that my dialect is SqlServer.  I've also replaced `DD` with `DAY`, but the problem remains.

How do I get hibernate to recognize that DD is a keyword?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue when upgrading from Sybase to SQLServer. The field in my scenario was an integer field used to store a date since 1970-01-01. The DATEADD function was used to convert that integer into a genuine date so we had a good representation through the hibernate mapped objects.

My original mapping for this field was the following:

```
<property name="lostDate" type="date">
  <formula>dateadd(dd, lost_date, '01-JAN-1970')</formula>
</property>
```

This resulted in the problem that you described in the question, where the resulting sql passed to the database was:

```
dateadd( table0_.dd, table0_.lost_date, '01-JAN-1970')
```

Updating the mapping to surround the dateadd keyword dd in double quotes resolved this issue for me.

```
<property name="lostDate" type="date">
  <formula>dateadd("dd", lost_date, '01-JAN-1970')</formula>
</property>
```

SQL Server 2008 accepted the generated SQL below and executed as expected.

```
dateadd("dd", table0_.lost_date, '01-JAN-1970')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, you can actually solve the problem by replacing **DD** with **"DD"**, but it won't work in some context.

Another technique that has solved everything in my case is to replace **DD** by **DAY** which is recognized by NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try replacing the expression with another not using DATEPART keywords.
Example - converting it to varchar back and forth:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with annotations. Quoting the date part worked for me as well.

```
@Formula("datediff(\"YEAR\", birthdate, current_timestamp)")
```